# Why is SQLErrorCode zero?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

In my Java program I'm using JDBC to access my PostgreSQL database and that is running fine. Trying to catch SQLExceptions does not really work.

My code:

```
...
catch (SQLException se) {
      System.out.println("\nSQLException: " + se.getMessage());
      SqlErrorCode = se.getErrorCode();
      System.out.println("\nSqlErrorCode: " + SqlErrorCode);
}
...
```

My query (generated by program):

```
SELECT osm_id, osm_type from   (SELECT osm_dach_admin_boundaries_old.osm_id,
       osm_dach_admin_boundaries_old.osm_type
  FROM osm_dach_admin_boundaries_old 
  FULL OUTER JOIN osm_dach_admin_boundaries
        ON (osm_dach_admin_boundaries_old.osm_id = osm_dach_admin_boundaries.osm_id 
       and osm_dach_admin_boundaries_old.osm_type = osm_dach_admin_boundaries.osm_type)
     WHERE (osm_dach_admin_boundaries_old.osm_id IS NULL 
     OR osm_dach_admin_boundaries.osm_id IS NULL)) foo
 WHERE osm_id is not null order by osm_id, osm_typeXXX;
```

Note the column osm_typeXXX, which I added to force an exception.

Running this query leads to

```
SQLException: ERROR: column "osm_typexxx" does not exist
  Hinweis: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "foo.osm_type".
  Position: 533

SqlErrorCode: 0
Closing source SQL-Connection
Closing destination SQL-Connection
```

Why is SqlErrorCode zero and how can I fix that?

Comment: Please do not put SOLVED in the question. If an answer solved your question then please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it. Only then, your question will be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

[`java.sql.SQLException.getErrorCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html#getErrorCode--) is documented as:

> Retrieves the vendor-specific exception code for this `SQLException` object.

Now PostgreSQL doesn't have vendor-specific error codes – it uses the standard conforming SQLSTATE instead.

So you should use [`java.sql.SQLException.getSQLState()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html#getSQLState--).